# Node js REST Service error add item to array

Tags: node.js, express

I have developed a specific REST Service that gives me an Array as a response.
I need to add one item String to this array, and I have used push() method, but in this way, the response shows my only the total number of items and not the value.
This is my code

```
router.get('/tire_brand', VerifyToken, function(req,res){
TechInfo.find().distinct('Brand', (err, techinfos) => {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).send({ status: 'ko', data: {msg: err.message }});
    console.log(err);
}
res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: {msg: 'Brands tires available', tires :techinfos.push('Other')}});
});
});
```

Any help on how to fix this problem and show array value and not length property?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `techinfos.push('Other')` returns the length of techinfos (have a look at the push method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)). If you do it like the following:

```
router.get('/tire_brand', VerifyToken, function(req,res){
  TechInfo.find().distinct('Brand', (err, techinfos) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).send({ status: 'ko', data: {msg: err.message }});
    console.log(err);
  }
  techinfos.push('Other'); // push an element here
  res.status(200).send({
    status: 'ok', data: {msg: 'Brands tires available', tires :techinfos}});
  });
});
```

You will get the techinfos arrays as desired.

Answer (score -1):

as per the [official documentation:](http://The%20push()%20method%20adds%20one%20or%20more%20elements%20to%20the%20end%20of%20an%20array%20and%20returns%20the%20new%20length%20of%20the%20array.)

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.

You can do this and it should work:

```
    // push the element first
    techinfos.push('Other');
    // and then send the response back
    res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: {msg: 'Brands tires available', tires :techinfos}});
```